# Is this the idiomatic way to bind to a non-RVO return value to be mutated?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, return-value-optimization

Let's assume an exemplary function, that can't be changed (e.g. because its linked against without the source code at hand), and it can't be subject to NRVO. Something like the following:

```
auto f()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> v2 { 2, 1, 3 };

    /* RVO impossible. */
    return someRuntimeCondition ? v1 : v2;
}
```

On the caller's side,

```
auto&& vec = f(); /* Extend lifetime to current scope. */

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); /* Const-lvalue ref. was no option. */
```

This should avoid move-constructing a local `std::vector` from the return value. But I don't see such snippets frequently. Am I wrong in my reasoning about the above snippets or are functions like `f()` so rare that relying on RVO is the more idiomatic apprach?

I am asking to understand how one should bind the return value of `f()` under the assumption that RVO is not applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17, if a function returns by value then the following two options are exactly the same:

- `auto a = f();`
- `auto&& a = f();`

except for the result of `decltype(a)`. The *result object* is named by `a` in both cases, and the result object is directly initialized by the `return` statement in the function.

---

Prior to C++17 the result object was always a temporary and `auto a = f();` copy-initialized `a` from the temporary, with this operation being optionally elidable.

Some people did use the practice of doing `auto&& a = f();` to defend against compilers which did not implement optional copy elision.  There are pros and cons to this.

Personally I use the former because I'm using C++17 , and even before that I only used compilers which did maximal copy elision. I'm not actually aware of any compiler that did not do copy elision here, except for old versions of MSVC running in Debug Mode.

But I can imagine people writing code bases for clients who use old compilers might feel the need to mangle their code for performance reasons.

Comment: The "pros and cons" have been discussed in more detail on here before although I haven't been able to find such discussions using the search function

Comment: Is it correct then that if NRVO applies, there is no move construction of the object `a` refers to (in both versions `auto a` and `auto a&&` above), but in the absence of NRVO, there will always be a move construction?

Comment: @lubgr it depends on the function internals ... if it returns a prvalue then there is no move construction .  That detail is an independent consideration to whether the calling code would do `auto a` or `auto&& a`.  The function initializes the result object, and the calling code controls where the result object will be

Comment: Allow me one last follow-up question here: the part `auto && __range = range_expression;` in [range based for loop expansions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is exclusively due to initializer_lists, not for avoiding copies of non-initializer_list range expressions, correct?

Comment: @lubgr I think it is so that forwarding reference rules are used to capture the range expression

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about an idiomatic way to deal with that but you could always do something like this:

```
auto f()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> rv { 2, 1, 3 }; // return value

    if(someRuntimeCondition)
        std::swap(v1, rv);

    return rv;
}
```

So you always make sure you only ever return one object;

An alternative approach occurs to me, like this:

```
auto f()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> v2 { 2, 1, 3 };

    return std::vector<int>{std::move(someRuntimeCondition ? v1 : v2)};
}
```

This should invoke `C++17`'s *guaranteed* RVO, moving whichever vector onto the caller's stack at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this clearly makes sense. But what if I don't know what's inside `f()` and I don't want to assume that RVO is possible?

Comment: @lubgr To be honest I'm not sure what the compiler does but in your code it has to put the object somewhere in the caller's stack in order to extend it's life span so either it does some RVO or it is going to have to copy something isn't it? Because when that function ends, all its object are going to be destroyed. So even in your code I suspect a copy will have to be made. Otherwise, where is your bound temporary going to live?

Comment: That sounds correct. I thought the lifetime extension of the return value might cause the rvalue reference referring to a variable living in the likewise lifetime-extended stack frame of `f()`, but this can't be the case?!

Comment: @lubgr Unfortunately I don't know for certain what happens otherwise I would have written that into the answer. As it is I just offered an alternative hoping someone with better knowledge in this area would properly answer your question.

Comment: All right, let's see then :) But thanks for your effort, this has already helped me clarifying the problem statement.

Comment: Concerning the guaranteed RVO, I assumed that capturing the return value with `auto&&` does even elide the move onto the caller's stack. But again, this might be impossible.